# Как сделать элементы в CardView кликабельными?

Tags: android, изображения, cardview, android-on-click

Смотрите у меня есть `CardView` в котором есть `изображение` и `текст`, но только при нажатии на текст выполняется действие которое я задавал на `CardView`.
Как сделать так что бы на элементы которые находятся внутри `CardView` распространялось действие.
**Отдельно писать действия под каждый Элемент не вариант. Так как элементов много и нужно будет писать под каждый свой ID**.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/calculator"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/card"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:src="@drawable/ex"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="@string/main_5"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Вот так я написал его в коде

```
public class Main extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    CardView сalculator;

 protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        calculator = findViewById(R.id.calculator);
        calculator.setOnClickListener(this);
   @Override
    public void onClick (View view) {
switch(view.getId()) {
case R.id.calculator:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Calculator.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                break;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"`

Comment: Уже пробовал убрать и добавлять к сожалению не помогает(

Comment: Добавлять это точно не нужно. Проверьте что и на остальных элементах этих значений нет. Ну или попробуйте `false` указать. Или на `LinearLayout` слушатель повесить.

Comment: `android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false" ` вот так нужно сделать?

Comment: Да, попробуйте так. Я точно не помню как именно эта штука работает, но дело должно быть в этом) Если вы весь код разметки показали, конечно и другие слушатели никуда не повешены)

Comment: Спасибо ваш ответ с  `android:clickable="false" android:focusable="false" ` подходит. Запишите его ответом и я вам его засчитаю) С Новым годом

Comment: Написал) Вас тоже с новым годом)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте установить

```
android:clickable="false" android:focusable="false"
```

для карточки. Это свойство указывает пропускать или нет событие клика по иерархии вьюх.

Comment: Кстати поздравляю Вас с тем что по мнению StackOverFlow на русском вы являетесь лучшим модератором прошлого года. Спасибо, что помогаете нам. Пускай и к Вам люди относятся так отзывчиво и хорошо как и Вы к ним.

Comment: @VladBulan, спасибо, очень приятно)